# How to disable JRebel "splash" screen / banner at startup

Tags: jvm, jrebel

Are there any options/flags I can pass to JRebel at start up to circumvent the splash screen displayed when JRebel starts up? It's causing a lot of mental noise by taking up a lot of space, and is not providing any useful information.

```
2014-07-18 16:05:41 JRebel: 
2014-07-18 16:05:41 JRebel: #############################################################
2014-07-18 16:05:41 JRebel: 
2014-07-18 16:05:41 JRebel:  JRebel 5.6.0 (201406201610)
2014-07-18 16:05:41 JRebel:  (c) Copyright ZeroTurnaround OU, Estonia, Tartu.
2014-07-18 16:05:41 JRebel: 
2014-07-18 16:05:41 JRebel:  Over the last 30 days JRebel prevented 
2014-07-18 16:05:41 JRebel:  at least 619 redeploys/restarts saving you about 25.1 hours.
2014-07-18 16:05:41 JRebel: 
2014-07-18 16:05:41 JRebel:  Over the last 124 days JRebel prevented
2014-07-18 16:05:41 JRebel:  at least 1366 redeploys/restarts saving you about 55.4 hours.
2014-07-18 16:05:41 JRebel: 
2014-07-18 16:05:41 JRebel:  This product is licensed to Erik Allik
...
```

I don't know how I would go about inspecting the options via `jrebel.jar`, nor was I able to google up anything.

The following documentation page does not provide any help either: http://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/standalone/config.html.

Comment: The URL you have pointed at is the application configuration chapter, about rebel.xml configuration file. Instead, the runtime options are listed in Miscellaneous chapter: http://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/misc/index.html As Joonas pointed out, the option that you're looking for does not exist - it is not implemented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edited, the flag to minimize the banner is available in JRebel 5.6.4-SNAPSHOT: **rebel.log.minimize_banner=true**

---

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a special flag that disables only the banner part, but there is an option to disable all messages to stdout.

3 Options:

1. JVM flag `-Drebel.log.stdout=false`
2. Write it to `{user.home}/.jrebel/jrebel.properties` as `rebel.log.stdout=false`
3. Toggle it from the IDE plugin settings

Actually it makes sense to make the banner optional, so I'll file a feature request.

Comment: disabling all output is also not desirable as the class reloading notifications are actually informative; could you please update the answer with the ticket URL you (will) have created?

Comment: JRebel doesn't currently use public ticket system, but the request is filed and linked to this thread, most likely will be notified here once implemented. (Can also ping support@zeroturnaround.com about JR-1636 if it seems to take long)

Comment: JRebel now allows you to minimize banner by using flag rebel.log.minimize_banner=true

This is not yet included in a release version, but is available from the nightly build https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/download/early-access/